# Why this while Javascript loop is infinite?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, qunit

I don't understand why this `while` loop is infinite:

```
window.prevRandomNumber = -1;
function getRandomNumber(limit) {
    if (!limit)
        limit = 9;

    var actualRandomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * limit) + 1);

    while (window.prevRandomNumber == actualRandomNumber) {
        actualRandomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * limit) + 1)
    }

    window.prevRandomNumber = actualRandomNumber;

    return actualRandomNumber;
}
```

QUnit test for this:

```
    test("getRandomNumber() should never return the same number once and again", function () {
        //http://www.askageek.com/2006/01/31/javascript-random-function-that-does-not-return-two-consecutive-identical-results/

        var prevNumber, actualNumber, assertResult;

        for (var i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
            actualNumber = getRandomNumber();
            assertResult = prevNumber != actualNumber;

            equal(assertResult, true);

            if (!assertResult)
                break;

            prevNumber = actualNumber;
        }
    });
```

**Solution:**

Sorry, the mistake was in another test, like describe by @Jon answer, when anyNumber equal a 1, infinite loop happens:

```
    test("getRandomNumber(anyNumber) should return a number between 1..anyNumber", function () {

        var anyNumber, result;

        for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            anyNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
            result = getRandomNumber(anyNumber);

            equal((0 < result && result < (anyNumber + 1)), true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What's the value of `limit`? For example, if `limit == 1` then it's an endless loop because of simple math.

Comment: Side note: You could make the code more DRY if you used a do...while loop.

Answer (score 7):

### Endless loop #1

The loop will be endless if `limit == 1`. Consider:

```
var actualRandomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * limit) + 1);
```

[`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns a number in the range [0, 1). Multiplying by `limit` does not change that, adding one brings it to [1, 2) so by definition `Math.floor` on that will return `1`.

```
while (window.prevRandomNumber == actualRandomNumber) {
    actualRandomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * limit) + 1)
}
```

Here we have the same logic, so:

- the first time the method is called it will return `1` (it will not go into a loop because `prevRandomNumber` is -1)
- the second and subsequent times the method will never return because `prevRandomNumber` will be already 1

I can't see how the loop would be infinite if `limit` is a number greater than 1.

### Endless loop #2

Consider what happens if `limit` is not a number.

```
var actualRandomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * limit) + 1);
```

Here, `Math.random() * limit` is going to be `NaN`, and so will the end result of the expression. So `actualRandomNumber` will *always* be equal to `NaN`. The method will return `Nan` the first time it's invoked and will not return the second time, for the same reason as above.

### Solution

```
function getRandomNumber(limit) {
    limit = Number(limit) || 9;

    var actualRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (limit + 1));
```

The first line fixes endless loop #2, and the second fixes loop #1 by adding 1 to limit before flooring the result. Therefore, if `limit` is 1 you will have

```
Math.floor( /* something in [0, 1) */ * 2 )
```

which is easy to see returns either 0 or 1 (and not *always* 1).

Comment: Yeah, even if I call getRandomNumber(9) from test, the while loop still in infinite.

Comment: @AcazSouza: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/mSbAA/). Are you sure it's `9` and not `"9"`?

Comment: Wait... I got a strange behavior, my limit is not always 9... Why? If I call getRandomNumber(9); limit is not always 9...

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure limit is always 9, but still remains infinite.

Comment: @AcazSouza: I don't know what does to an infinite loop, but this code does not. See the link I gave above.